# How to add specific answers to specific questions in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new to using Dialogflow,and I want to create a simple DialogFlow bot that can answer basic addition,subtraction,multiplication,division questions.How would I code it that it responds to the specific question asked by the user? For example if I made a math intent, I used the training phase "What's 2 x 3", and I made the response "6". Now, I want to add more training phases and I need the bot to use the correct response. Also, another problem is that it would take an impossible amount of time to teach it every possible math question,so is there code I could use to change that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to be able to answer every combination of math question would be by using a [fulfillment webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview). Here you can use code to do the calculations based on the user input. You could create an addition intent where you train the bot to recognize addition input and you would connect it to code in your webhook which can do additions and return the response. You can then also add intents for subtracting, multiplication and divisions and connect each of those intents to code which can do the math.

For the setup, you have two options. You can write code in the inline editor in Dialogflow or host your code in your own server and connect dialogflow to the url of that server. More info on that can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-configure).